# Can't duplicate development environment for LifeRay 6.1.10 EE

Tags: liferay-6

I have a fully working development environment for Liferay 6.1.10 EE (using Liferay Development Studio). I already made some new layouts succesfully.

Now I need to copy the database dump from another developer as a base of my instance. I have the database dump injected into my db and I can see that the data is there. Also the other developer has done the same earlier (succesfully). (Also I recall doing this earlier myself with LR 5.2.3 CE)

However when I enter the instance from browser I am greeted with the license agreement page and a form for setting a new security question with answer. After accepting, these won't be asked again in subsequent boots.
However when I re-insert the database dump, the license agreement will be asked again. (The EE license has been inserted to deploy dir, but it doesn't seem to have any effect if it is/was there or not. Probably it can be found with the database dump).

The thing is that there is no sign about the site which this other developer has done, though the data is suppose to be there (in db).
Also dropping the database will end in error that it isn't found. (Not a single error otherwise)

I have tried copying the whole webapps dir (from the other developer), and also removed all the jackrabbit configurations (and deleted it's 'home' directory, that it creates). No effect.

Also tried deleting the 'work' and 'temp' directory contents of Tomcat (7.0.25) to be sure, there isn't anything.

Have been browsing on:
http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/1071674/Backup+and+restore

It says "Zip the document_library folder, which contains all documents and files from the document library." << I assume this is not needed as we don't have any 'Document Library'.
Either way. I assume I should see something atleast!?

Comment: The result after injecting the db dump is actually the same if I am using an empty database (LR creates new tables itself)

Comment: Tried copying the the whole 'data' directory aswell, as editing the jacrabbit repository.xml and workspace.xml files with correct database info.

Comment: Also requested a new trial license from liferay, inserted it into deploy dir from which it was deployed. Everything looks like ok as I got past the 'license-nagging' page. Also I can see this line in the log >>09:11:51,640 INFO  [LicenseManager:?] Portal Development license validation passed<<. This is kind of puzzling as the trial is for version 6.1 GA2... Anyway, if it's ok for liferay, it's ok for me. But still I have no site copied.

Comment: I looked on the license (developer) info and it has 'expiration date' : 'Friday, August 5, 2112 7:00:00 AM GMT' and 'begin date' : 'Wednesday, August 29, 2012 7:00:00 AM GMT'. (valid for ~100 years)

I suspected the license checking could have some issues with the date, so I tested setting date before the 'start date' on my development machine.

After the date-edit I will be moved to 'license-nagging' page (seems legit).
However changing the date date back to 'real date', has no more effect. It thinks the license has expired/is invalid and I will only get the 'licence-nagging' page now.

Comment: I am not sure what kind of behaviour is expected if the license is invalid. I can not find any information related to this.
How ever the behaviour I experience is far from anything sane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to the fact that MySQL 'my.cnf' didn't have:

```
[mysqld]
lower_case_table_names=1
```

Liferay tried to use table names starting with upper case (like 'Account_'), when the dump had the table names with lower case (like 'account_').

Of course I had the "create default tables" on with liferay, so I ended up with an empty-liferay when it started.

The 'lower case table names' option originated from undocumented environment history by a person no longer in the house.